# JDBC connection to very busy SQL 2000: selectMethod=cursor vs selectMethod=direct?

Tags: jdbc, sql-server-2000, database-cursor, selectmethod

In the process of trying to help out an app dev team with performance issues on a SQL 2000 server (from a bunch of Java applications on separate app servers), I ran a SQL trace and discovered that all calls to the database are full of API Server Cursor statements (sp_cursorprepexec, sp_cursorfetch, sp_cursorclose).

Looks like they're specifying some connection string properties that force the use of server-side cursors, retrieving only 128 rows of data at a time: (From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa172588)

> When the API cursor attributes or
>   properties are set to anything other
>   than their defaults, the OLE DB
>   provider for SQL Server and the SQL
>   Server ODBC driver use API server
>   cursors instead of default result
>   sets. Each call to an API function
>   that fetches rows generates a
>   roundtrip to the server to fetch the
>   rows from the API server cursor.

**UPDATE**: The connection string at issue is a JDBC connection string parameter, `selectMethod=cursor` (which enables the server-side cursors we discussed above) vs the alternative `selectMethod=direct`. They have been using `selectMethod=cursor` as their standard connection string from all apps.

From my DBA perspective, that's just annoying (it clutters the trace up with useless junk), and (I would speculate) is resulting in many extra app-to-SQL server round trips, reducing overall performance.

They apparently did test changing (just one of about 60 different app connections) to `selectMethod=direct` but experienced some issues (of which I have no details) and are concerned about the application breaking.

So, my questions are:

- Can using `selectMethod=cursor` lower application performance, as I have tried to argue? (by increasing the number of round trips necessary on a SQL server that already has a very high queries/sec)
- Is `selectMethod=` an application-transparent setting on a JDBC connection? Could this break their app if we change it?
- More generally, when should you use `cursor` vs `direct`?

Also [cross-posted to SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/177391/).

**EDIT**: Received actual technical details that warrant a significant edit to title, question, and tags.

**EDIT**: Added bounty. Also added bounty to the SF question (this question is focused on application behavior, the SF question is focused on SQL performance.) Thanks!!

Comment: IIRC, you're right. This does seem like a ServerFault question as much as a SO one, though.   You'd probably be smart to ask at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/ too.

Comment: I've mentioned it on the #sqlhelp tag on twitter. No bites there, either. I think its considered bad form to cross-post a question across multiple SO sites, right?

Comment: My best guess would be that they should try it. Maybe they've got UnitTests which they can fire against the database with the changed connection string (or a little test application).

Comment: I don't see why it would be, and Q's get cross-posted all the time -- especially when they are "moderated" from one site to another, 2 copies remain.  If you get good answers on one site, just be sure to link back to the other (to help future searchers).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Briefly,

1. `selectMethod=cursor`

   - theoretically requires [more server-side resources](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/cursors_p1.aspx) than `selectMethod=direct`
   - only loads at most *batch-size* records into client memory at once, resulting in a more predictable client memory footprint
2. `selectMethod=direct`

   - theoretically requires less server-side resources than `selectMethod=cursor`
   - will read the entire result set into client memory (unless the driver natively supports asynchronous result set retrieval) before the client application can iterate over it; this **can reduce performance in two ways**:

     1. reduced performance with large result sets if the client application is written in such a way as to stop processing after traversing only a fraction of the result set (with `direct` it has already paid the cost of retrieving data it will essentially throw away; with `cursor` the waste is limited to at most *batch-size* - 1 rows -- the early termination condition should probably be recoded in SQL anyway e.g. as `SELECT TOP` or window functions)
     2. reduced performance with large result sets because of potential garbage collection and/or out-of-memory issues associated with an increased memory footprint

In summary,

- *Can using `selectMethod=cursor` lower application performance?* -- either method can lower performance, for different reasons.  Past a certain resultset size, `cursor` may still be preferable.  See below for when to use one or the other
- *Is `selectMethod=` an application-transparent setting on a JDBC connection?* -- it is transparent, but it can still break their app if memory usage grows significantly enough to hog their client system (and, correspondingly, your server) or crash the client altogether
- *More generally, when should you use `cursor` vs `direct`?* -- I personally use `cursor` when dealing with potentially large or otherwise unbounded result sets.  The roundtrip overhead is then amortized given a large enough batch size, and my client memory footprint is predictable.  I use `direct` when the size of the result set I expect is known to be inferior to whatever batch size I use with `cursor`, or bound in some way, or when memory is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks, vladr. Sounds like its a setting that would take some testing. I know the app server is pretty busy, so perhaps it was a memory issue that caused some of the problems when they turned this off.

Answer (score 1):

Using `selectMethod=cursor` prevents SQL Server from using [Parallel Query Processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178065%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which can have a big performance impact, for example when:

- you have many CPU cores (and who doesn't?)
- you have optimized your database by partitioning tables
- you are running lots of aggregate queries (`sum()`, `count()`, etc.)

Finally, Microsoft [states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988.aspx) the following:

> (*`selectMethod=direct`*) provides the fastest performance when the application is processing all rows.

You should definitely try and see if setting selectMethod=direct makes a difference for you.